# Changing a nonspecific file name with python

Tags: python, selenium

So I am using selenium and python to automate a web process. The process downloads several files and the files are named by the current time. For example 'ExampleFile173058' for a file that was downloaded at 17:30:58pm now of course this changes depending on the time.

I need to write some code that will rename this^ file with yesterdays date, for example 'FileName-01-10-2018' for a file created on the 02/10/2018. I know that this* code can be used to rename files, but Im unsure how to make it recognize the original file name that is time stamped. Im also unsure how to rename the file with yesterdays date.

```
import os

os.rename('a.txt', 'b.kml')
```

Comment: Do you want to use the fileobjects creation time and substract 1 day?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clarify exactly what you want. From reading your question, it sounds like you're wanting to do the following:

1. find a list of files in a folder and get their file names.
2. Parse those file names into dates and suitably alter to subtract a day
3. do the rename.

Suggestions:

1. you could use os.listdir if you don't need recursive folder search.
2. you could use a regex (python's [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module)

Here's some useful references:

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-datetime-time-examples

And a related SO question:

[Working with time, date, timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608481/working-with-time-date-timedelta)